# Is it possible to test NFC pass functionality on a device without having an NFC certificate?

Tags: ios, passbook, passkit, pkpass

I've created a pass.json file that will sign and open flawlessly as long as I omit the NFC dictionary. On my device, I've enabled the developer setting "NFC Pass Key Optional" which I initially thought would allow me to bypass NFC Certificate verification and allow for me to test the unencrypted data. Upon attempting to open the certificate with an NFC dictionary included, I get an error stating there was an issue with the wallet file I should open the pkpass file in files.

Upon reviewing the console, I was able to find the following error from com.apple.passkit - "Passes with an NFC dictionary or a Personalization JSON file must be signed with an enhanced Passbook certificate."

Are my initial thoughts incorrect and regardless of the developer option you are required to have the enhanced NFC Passbook certificate to open an NFC pkpass or is there a setting that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the (popular?) Nuget package dotnet-passbook.

I get contacted a lot by developers looking to use NFC functionality. Unfortunately, it seems the only way to get access to those keys is by getting an enhanced certificate.

I've not heard of anyone having any success otherwise.

Comment: we got the entitlements for the app from apple. Where can we get this enhanced certificate?

Comment: I believe they'll be included in the passkit certificate when you generate it.